# Is there some standard functionality in XNA to efficiently implement a 2D Camera on a large world

Tags: data-structures, performance, xna, 2d

I am making a 2d space game with many moving objects. I have already implemented a camera that can move around and draw the objects within the view. The problem now is that I have to check for every object wether it is within the rectangle of my view before I draw it (O(*n*) operations where *n* is the number of objects in my world). I would like a more efficient way to acquire all the objects within the view so I only have to draw them.

I know a bunch of data structures that can achieve a O(log *n* + *k*) query time for a two dimensional range query, where *k* is the amount of objects within the range. The problem is that all the objects are constantly moving. The update time on most of the data structures is O(log *n*) as well. This is pretty bad because almost all objects are moving so all will have to be updated resulting in O(*n* log *n*) operations. With my current implementation (everything is just stored in a list), the update time takes O(*n*) operations to update everything.

I am thinking that this problem must have been solved already, but I couldn't really find a solution that specifically considers my options. Most 2D camera examples just do it the way I am currently doing.

So my question basically consists out of two things:

1. Is there a more efficient way to do this than my current one (in general)?
2. Is there a more efficient way to do this than my current one (in XNA)?

On one hand I am thinking, O(*n*) + O(*n*) is better than O(log *n*) + O(*n* log *n*), but on the other hand I know that in many games they use all these data structures like BSPs etc. So I feel like I am missing some piece of the puzzle.

PS: I am a bit confused whether I should post this on Stack Overflow, the Game Developers stack exchange or the Computer Science Theory stack exchange...... So please excuse me if it's a bit out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question would be: are you *really* going to have a world with a million (or even a billion!) objects?

This is a performance optimisation, so here's what I would do:

First of all: nothing. Just draw everything and update everything every frame, using a big list. Suitable for tens of objects.

If that is too slow, I would do some basic culling as I iterated the list. So for each object - if it is off-screen, don't draw it. If it is "unimportant" (eg: a particle system, other kinds of animation, etc) don't update it while off-screen either. Suitable for hundreds of objects.

(You need to be able to get an object's position and bounding box, and check compare it with the screen's rectangle.)

And finally, if that is too slow, I would implement a bucketed data structure (constant update time, constant query time). In this case a 2D grid of lists that covers your world space. Suitable for thousands of objects.

If that ends up taking up too much memory - if your world is crazy-large and sparse - I would start looking into quadtrees, perhaps. And remember that **you don't have to update the space-partitioning structure every time you update an object** - only when an object's position changes significantly!

Remember the idiom: *Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work*. Implement the simple case, and then actually see if your game is running slowly with a real-world number of objects, before you go implementing something complicated.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I will do it like you say and make it so that I can easily change it.

Comment: If you don't update the quadtrees, wouldn't you risk the data "bleeding" into adjacent buckets? What would be considered a "significant" update? I realize that it would be a strain to change things every update cycle, but it feels like it would be lossy and prone to inaccurate data.

Comment: @KyleBaran I probably meant (I'm guessing, because the answer is 4 years old) that you don't have to do a remove/insert operation every frame. You'd only re-bucket if the bucket changed. Relating to the original question: even if insert is a "slow" operation, you don't have to do it every frame, so performance may be acceptable. A "loose quadtree" is the data structure you describe - it's a valid data structure - requires even less updating. It would be the next step up in complexity, so continuing the theme from the answer: you wouldn't do that unless you really needed to.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say, you check every object that you wish to put on to screen & take action against whether or not it is inside the specified screen area???

XNA takes care of handling objects which are out of screen (by not drawing of course) automatically, You simply specify the coordinates... Or did I misunderstand you question??

**EDIT**

Why not use a container sprite, draw everything you want inside it & then draw that single main sprite onto the screen? Calling draw on that single sprite won't really involve drawing of those parts which are outside.

Comment: I check every object in the world to see if it is visible on the screen. This usually translates into calling Draw on every object and the framework will then draw it or not depending on whether it is inside the visible area. But that still entails an operation for every object in the world. I would rather not call Draw on objects that are not visible anyway.

Comment: There are data structures that store the objects in such a way that it can give you all objects within a rectangle while only looking at O(log n) objects + the amount of object in the rectangle. For a world with a million objects, this will result in me calling draw about 20 times instead of a million times (with a world of a billion objects it will be about 30 times instead of a billion times). I would like to make use of such a data structure, but I have a problem that all my objects are moving so I would have to update the data structure a lot which takes a lot of time.