# XNA: Have I clicked on anything?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm making a game in XNA and currently I'm checking the coordinates of the mouse click against the coordinates of each object that can be clicked.

This is fine for my small game but for larger games it would become CPU intensive to check through every object for each frame.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how many objects. Wouldn't it be easier to always pass the click event, and if an object was clicked, have the object determine if something should happen?

Comment: You might get better answers on the Game Development site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So instead each object would check to see if the mouse clicked it?

Comment: This is a performance question, so the answer is, of course, **profile it**. This is something you shouldn't have to worry about until your'e getting into the 1000s of objects. And you have even less to worry about if it's per-click, rather than per-frame!

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524710/xna-2d-mouse-picking/4525667#4525667

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to partition your world space with some sort of algorithm like [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

In your most basic form you'll want to be able to take all objects and be able to quickly throw out a bunch of them before you even do your detailed check.  For instance, if you are clicking on the right side of the screen you want to throw out everything on the left side of the screen automagically.

Comment: Looks like I have a new way of describing how computers work. +1

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I suppose the question for me now is whether or not it would be worth implementing this considering I will only have between 10 and 20 objects that the player can actually click.

Comment: probably not worth it for 10/20 objects.